# Finding the location of the most recent occurrence of a string across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a table that looks like this:

| p1 name | p2 Name | p3 Name | p 4 name | p1 Pre-Game ELO | p2 Pre-Game ELO | p3 Pre-Game ELO | p4 Pre-Game ELO | p1 Post-Game ELO | p2 Post-Game ELO | p3 Post-Game ELO | p4 Post-Game ELO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Stacy | Derek | Joel | 1500 | 1500 | 1500 | 1500 | 1560 | 1440 | 1440 | 1440 |
| Stacy | George | Donny | Ivanka | x | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |

For the second row, to determine each player's pre-game ELO, I need to find each player's most recent Post-Game ELO. This is difficult, because I do not know if Dan's most recent game was as player 1, player 2, player 3 or player 4.

How can I perform this lookup?

I have tried VLookup, but that only outputs a value in some given column. I need different columns depending on which place the player was most recently in.

There can be many more than two rows. The table will extend over time as more games are submitted.

Comment: Where does `Dan` enter into it?  I don't see any `Dan` listed.  And `Donny` and `Ivanka` are only listed in the one row.  What would their most recent Post Game ELO be?

Comment: Sorry - replace `Dan` with `Donny`.

Their most recent Post-Game ELO will be their post-game ELO of their only game.

Each player's pre-game ELO is 1500 if they do not have any previous games.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, or adapt the following:

```
=INDEX($I$2:L5,    MAX(($A$2:D5=A6) * (ROW($A$2:D5) - 1)),    MAX(INDEX(  ($A$2:D5=A6) * COLUMN($A$2:D5),  MAX(($A$2:D5=A6) * (ROW($A$2:D5) - 1)),)  ))
```

By "adapt" I mean adjust ranges, of course, but also that it does not provide for errors such as the "Donny/Ivanka" one `Ron Rosenfeld` mentions in his comment. I'm figuring two things:  that you don't need help there, and that real data would not have such glaring troubles. However, the latter goes out the window if one is typing each new line of names...

Basically, it finds the rows that have the name desired in the Row parameter of the inner `INDEX` function using the TRUE/FALSE test of the cells in the range ABOVE the current line equaling the name being checked, and then finds the `MAX` value out of that array of values. That gives the most recent row in the data ABOVE the current line in which the name occurs.

So, why do I emphasize "ABOVE"? Because how you do that is particular. You use absolute referencing for the first cell in the range and relative referencing for the last cell in the range. That way, when copied down rows, the data range not only expands by a row for each row copied down, but it also is always all the rows above the current row without needing any volatile functions. (Not because I assume the data could never get so big that they would slow Excel down (though I do), but rather because finding the pieces to use in them is often "long-winded" and calculation intensive in itself.)

So, now one has the nearest row so one has narrowed the value down to one of four cells' values in that row. Which of them? Well, finding the column would answer that and the next piece of the formula does that (the Column parameter in the inner `INDEX` function).

The `INDEX` again uses the name portion of the bigger table, taking the row learned by the above calculation and testing for TRUE/FALSE in each of the cells multiplying by the column number for each to get one non-zero value with a series of zero values. `MAX` susses that value out as the Column parameter needed.

So now one has the row to look in and which of the four (or however many are needed for the real life usage) columns. That column value is the same to the far right in the four columns with post-game ELO's. So the outer `INDEX` uses those four columns of the full table and the row/column values learned above to select the proper post-game ELO to return for the name looked for.

As it stands, it will simply have an Excel error returned (which ought to be easy to spot, especially as only a single line is being looked at at any given moment) for most failures I picture happening. But it is conceivable, as it ALWAYS is, that a failure could return a real-looking value instead of an Excel error. I'm pretty sure only human input could be a problem here, but you know how "pretty sure" goes in real life.

So buyer beware!

*(If desired, one can remove the extra spaces I put in to help delineate the functional areas of the formula, just paste the formula into a proper cell and press `Enter` to set it. Then open it again with `F2`, add a (wholly inappropriate) parentheses to the end and press `Enter` again. Excel will catch that error and ask you to accept a version of things without it. Accept that. Notice that it tightens it up as well, removing the extra spaces.)*